# BizTalk: Clearing password from send port for custom adapter when exporting binding for application

Tags: binding, passwords, adapter, biztalk, baseadapter

I have problems clearing a password, when exporting an application containing a send port using an adapter I've made for BizTalk Server 2010.

The send port uses an adapter I've made, based upon the Microsoft.Samples.BizTalk.Adapter.Common BaseAdapter (v.1.0.2).

Both the TransmitLocation.xsd and TransmitHandler.xsd schema uses the AdapterFramework password specific field, and both are defined as:

```
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" default="" name="passwordField">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <baf:designer xmlns:baf="BiztalkAdapterFramework.xsd">
              <baf:category _locID="mailAuthIndstillingerKategori">Password related category</baf:category>
              <baf:displayname _locID="passwordName">Password:</baf:displayname>
              <baf:description _locID="passwordDescription">Password description.</baf:description>
              <baf:editor assembly="%BTSROOT%\\Developer Tools\\Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.dll">Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.ComponentModel.PasswordUITypeEditor</baf:editor>
              <baf:converter assembly="%BTSROOT%\\Developer Tools\\Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.dll">Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.ComponentModel.PasswordTypeConverter</baf:converter>
            </baf:designer>
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="50" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

Some google-hits mention that setting the '**vt="1"**' attribute, on the element which should be cleared, should do the trick. I've tried setting / adding this attribute when the **ValidateConfiguration()** is called. But the configuration-XML is returned as a string which is then escaped before inserted into the **<CustomProps>** xml, being exported in the binding file.

I've tried specifying that the **SendHandlerPropertiesXML** and **SendLocationPropertiesXML**'s **AdapterConfig**, in the registry entry, should use the following **<CustomProps>**, with the **vt="1"** attribute, in hope that it would blank out the entire binding properties for the port (not optimal, but a better solution than letting someone export the password):

```
SendHandlerPropertiesXML : <CustomProps><AdapterConfig vt="1"/></CustomProps>
SendLocationPropertiesXML : <CustomProps><AdapterConfig vt="1"/></CustomProps>
```

When the application with the configured send port is exported, the specific XML looks like the following:

```
<TransportTypeData>&lt;CustomProps&gt;&lt;AdapterConfig vt="1"&gt;&amp;lt;Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;passwordField vt="1"&amp;gt;CLEARTEXTPASSWORD;lt;/passwordField&amp;gt;&amp;lt;uri&amp;gt;SMTP://NOT-USED&amp;lt;/uri&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Config&amp;gt;&lt;/AdapterConfig&gt;&lt;/CustomProps&gt;</TransportTypeData>
```

Everytime the binding is exported, the adapter's overloaded method: **ValidateConfiguration()** is called, but there's no way to tell if this is when the adapter has been configured, or when the bindings are being exported, meaning: you can't mangle the password in the xml-string being returned, as it will also mangle the password when being configured.

There are other built-in adapters that do this (E.G.: SMTP adapter), and I'm sure it's something basic that I'm misunderstanding. But any help or pointers would be very helpfull.

Comment: I thought passwords were never included when bindings are exported.

Comment: With all the adapters that are pre-installed with BTS this is the case. But when you make your own adapter, you have to somehow tell BTS, that when a specific element (the password) in the binding is being exported, it should blank it or "star" it.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the [Blogical Sftp Adapter](http://sftpadapter.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex made this work and I've been able to replicate it.

All you should have to do is add `type="baf:Password"` on the password elements.

You can reference their schema [here](http://sftpadapter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Blogical.Adapters.Sftp/Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.Management/TransmitLocation.xsd).